# using Powershell to extract data out of log files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to script pulling key elements out of some log files and displaying it on screen using PowerShell.

I've got a command that works, but it's sloppy. I'm using the follow command which simply looks for the string (representing the host name of a computer) and returns the entire line of output on the screen.  I have a number of log files going back two years or so.

```
$Hostname = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Input computer name: ').ToUpper()
Write-host "Searching for a computer with " $hostname " in the computer name"
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\users\username\downloads\deletedcomputers" -Recurse -File -Filter "*log" | select-string -Pattern $hostname | Group path | select group
```

What I would like to do, is pull some of the fields out.  We have essentially two functions: Move and Delete.

I would like to display on the screen the action (Move | Delete), the host name, the source OU, and the date.

So the output would look something like this:

```
Move computer A-BKM2ZZZZ to Disabled Computers from OU All Admins, Finance on 03-24-2020
Delete computer A-GM7XXXXX from Disabled Computers on 03-24-2020
```

I've been poking around with get-content and trying to isolate the 'fields' but I'm having little success.

Here are a couple lines from the log file

```
<![LOG["AD Clean": Action 22:00:18 - Move A-BKM2ZZZZ to Disabled Computers OU success. CN=A-BKM2ZZZZ,OU=All Admins,OU=FINANCE,OU=ABC,OU=Workstations,OU=Company,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=com]LOG]!><time="22:00:18.372+300" date="03-24-2020" component="Info" context="" type="1" thread="" file="">

<![LOG["AD Clean": Action 22:00:18 - Stale systems over 120 old to be removed: (29 found)]LOG]!><time="22:00:18.519+300" date="03-24-2020" component="Info" context="" type="1" thread="" file="">  

<![LOG["AD Clean": Action 22:00:18 - Delete A-GM7XXXXX from Disabled Computers OU success. CN=A-GM7XXXXX,OU=Disabled Computers,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=com]LOG]!><time="22:00:18.582+300" date="03-24-2020" component="Info" context="" type="1" thread="" file="">  

<![LOG["AD Clean": Action 22:00:18 - Delete A-D57XXXXX from Disabled Computers OU success. CN=A-D57XXXXX,OU=Disabled Computers,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=com]LOG]!><time="22:00:18.631+300" date="03-24-2020" component="Info" context="" type="1" thread="" file="">  

<![LOG["AD Clean": Action 22:00:18 - Delete B-2XLXXXXX from Disabled Computers OU success. CN=B-2XLXXXXX,OU=Disabled Computers,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=com]LOG]!><time="22:00:18.679+300" date="03-24-2020" component="Info" context="" type="1" thread="" file="">
```

the log files are generated by an automated process that moves and deletes stale computers in active directory.

Comment: What is `$hostname` defined as?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\users\username\downloads\deletedcomputers" -Recurse -File -Filter "*log"
Get-Content -Path $files -Raw | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -split '(?:\r?\n){2,}' -cmatch '\bMove\b|\bDelete\b' | Foreach-Object {
        $matches = $null
        $null = $_ -match '\b(?<Action>Move|Delete)\b (?<Host>\S+) .*?(?<OU>CN=[^\]]+).*?date="(?<date>[^"]+)'
        [pscustomobject]$matches | Select Action,Host,OU,Date
    }
}
```

`Get-ChildItem` is used to store your file object list in `$files`. Since [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7)'s `-Path` parameter supports an array of paths, we can pass `$files` into it. The `-Raw` switch reads in a file as a single string.

Since the `-match` operator uses regex to perform matching, there are numerous regex mechanisms to consider.

- The `.` character is any character. It is only a literal dot when preceded by `\`, the regex escape character.
- `+` is one or more of the preceding character. So `a+` is one or more `a`.
- `*` without a succeeding `?` is a greedy match. `.*` matches any character as many times as possible.
- `*?` is a lazy match and matches as few characters as possible. `a*?b` matches as few `a` as possible until `b` is found.
- `\S` is a non-space character.
- `[]` is a character class match. Anything within the `[]` can be matched and it uses `OR` logic. `^` within `[]` negates the succeeding character.
- `\r` matches carriage return.
- `\n` matches line feed.
- `?` without a preceding `*` is zero or one of the preceding character. So `g?` is zero or one `g`.

It appears your log entries are delimited by multiple `CRLF` characters. Based on that assumption, you can split each entry into a separate string by `\r?\n{2,}`.

Each time `-match` or `-cmatch` (case-sensitive match) is successful, the `$matches` automatic variable is updated with the match contents. The syntax `(?<label>)` creates a capture group called `label` and is added as a key to the `$matches` hash table. Its matching value can be retrieved using `$matches.label`.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out.  I wish I could use Linux AWK, SED and GREP.  I'd have had this done a long time ago.

Comment: I haven't been able to make that work, i get errors & apparently I'm still not smart enough to figure out how to get the $hostname variable involved there either.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$hostname` in this case?

Comment: it's the name of the computer in active directory.

Comment: Would you expect $hostname to be the string after computer in your file? So instead of seeing all Delete or Move items, you only want to see the ones for a certain computer that you enter as $hostname? If that is he case, you could just pipe my output to `where host -eq $hostname`

Comment: Good morning. 
I've been away for a bit on PTO. Haven't had a chance to circle back to this, although one of the things i wanted to work on while off work was getting this script to work. 

In the log file sample entries, the host name is usually formatted like A-XXXXXXX but occasionally has a different prefix.  Ex: ABC-JX124BQ

Right now, I can get the results I want just not in a clean format.  I'm simply pattern matching what the user types in for the hostname and scanning 2 years worth of log files looking for deleted devices simply to identify how long ago the device was deleted.